# how to remove duplicate list and get the new list in for loop operation

Tags: database, flutter, dart, data-structures, dart-null-safety

I have the following list of maps:

```dart
[
   {
      "ExtendedDutyId":1,
      "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
      "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
      "FromTime":"0:00",
      "ToTime":"36:00",
      "Allowance":0,
      "ShiftType":-1,
      "ShiftCode":-1,

      "Employee":{
         "EmployeeId":1025,
         "FirstName":"Daniel",
         "LastName":"Hansen-Hansen",
         "CompanyCode":"BY"
      }
   },
   {
      "ExtendedDutyId":1,
      "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
      "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
      "FromTime":"5:11",
      "ToTime":"10:29",
      "Allowance":0,
      "ShiftType":-1,
      "ShiftCode":1314679,
      "Employee":{
         "EmployeeId":1025,
         "FirstName":"Daniel",
         "LastName":"Hansen-Hansen",
         "CompanyCode":"BY"
      }
   },
   {
      "ExtendedDutyId":1,
      "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
      "DutyDate":"2022-10-27",
      "FromTime":"0:00",
      "ToTime":"36:00",
      "Allowance":0,
      "ShiftType": -1,
      "ShiftCode":-1,
      "Employee":{
         "EmployeeId":1025,
         "FirstName":"Daniel",
         "LastName":"Hansen-Hansen",
         "CompanyCode":"BY"
      }
   }
]
```

I would like to manipulate the above data such that data are grouped by their `DateOfBirth`, so that result would look like this:

```dart
{
   "employeeTimeRegStatus":[
      {
         "supervisor":1035,
         "employeeId":1025,
         "companyCode":"BY",
         "statusId":1,
         "timeRegs":[
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
               "FromTime":0,
               "ToTime":2160,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":-1,
               "Allowance":0
            },
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-27",
               "FromTime":0,
               "ToTime":2160,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":-1,
               "Allowance":0
            },
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
               "FromTime":311,
               "ToTime":629,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":1314679,
               "Allowance":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "supervisor":1035,
         "employeeId":1025,
         "companyCode":"BY",
         "statusId":1,
         "timeRegs":[
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
               "FromTime":0,
               "ToTime":2160,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":-1,
               "Allowance":0
            },
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-27",
               "FromTime":0,
               "ToTime":2160,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":-1,
               "Allowance":0
            },
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
               "FromTime":311,
               "ToTime":629,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":1314679,
               "Allowance":0
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "supervisor":1035,
         "employeeId":1025,
         "companyCode":"BY",
         "statusId":1,
         "timeRegs":[
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
               "FromTime":0,
               "ToTime":2160,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":-1,
               "Allowance":0
            },
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-27",
               "FromTime":0,
               "ToTime":2160,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":-1,
               "Allowance":0
            },
            {
               "ExtendedDutyId":1,
               "DutyName":"Overtime duties",
               "DutyDate":"2022-10-26",
               "FromTime":311,
               "ToTime":629,
               "ShiftType":-1,
               "ShiftCode":1314679,
               "Allowance":0
            }
         ]
      }
   ],
  
}
```

I have tried to solve this but getting the error:

```
The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'
```

When I tried to insert `putIfAbsent` employee:

```dart
    final value = xdata.fold(Map<String, List<dynamic>>(), 
       (Map<String, List<dynamic>> a, b) {
           a.putIfAbsent(b["Employee"]!["FirstName"].toString(), () 
             => []).add(b);
               return a;
             }).values
                .where((l) => l.isNotEmpty)
                .map((l) => {
       
                'Supervisor': l.first["Supervisor"],
                'employeeId': l.first["employeeId"],
                'companyCode': l.first["companyCode"],
                'statusId': l.first["statusId"],

                'TimeRegs': l.map((e) => {
                'ExtendedDutyId': e['ExtendedDutyId'],
                'DutyName': e['DutyName'],
                'DutyDate': e['DutyDate'],
                'FromTime': e['FromTime'],
                'ToTime': e['ToTime'],
                'ShiftType': e['ShiftType'],
                'ShiftCode': e['ShiftCode'],
                'Allowance': e['Allowance'],
              }).toList()
            }).toList();
```

As I am new to dart and flutter, I am not sure what to do. Can anybody help me with this?

model for employeeTimeRegstatus:

```
class EmployeeTimeRegStatus {
      int? supervisor;
      int? employeeId;
      String? companyCode;
      int? statusId;
      List<TimeRegs>? timeRegs;

   EmployeeTimeRegStatus(
         {this.supervisor,
         this.employeeId,
         this.companyCode,
         this.statusId,
         this.timeRegs});}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share the code of this TimeRegs function or tell what this function is doing?

Comment: TimeRegs model is used to get list from server which i add at first of question

Comment: i am doing something wrong in for loop and i am not sure what it is

Comment: TimeRegs is returning list or map?

Comment: TimeRegs returns list

Comment: can you share your code in dartpad or github to find out whats going wrong